# navCtrl navigation to next page ionic

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework, controller, ionic2

I have some issue with my code. Can't navigate from home page to for example about page. The application is in ionic framework. Totally new in this technology. In console no warnings and errors.
home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Auth } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';
import { User } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
import { About } from '../about/about';
import { ChatPage } from '../chat/chat';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,  public auth: Auth, public user: User) {
    console.log(user);
  }

  logout() {
      this.auth.logout();
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
    }

   about(){
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(About);
    }

    chat(){
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(ChatPage);
    }
}
```

home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Home
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="logout()">
        <ion-icon name="exit"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Welcome back, {{ user.details.name }}</h2>
  <p>
    <button ion-button color="secondary" block>Something</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button ion-button color="secondary" block [navPush]="ChatPage">Chat</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button ion-button color="secondary" block [navPush]="About">About</button>
  </p>
</ion-content>
```

about.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html',
})
export class About {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad About');
  }

}
```

about.html

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>about</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding class="about">
  This is my super awesome about page.
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible and easy solution is call method on click of button. As you are defining `about()` method in home.ts now call this method on click of button. just update code in home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Home
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="logout()">
        <ion-icon name="exit"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Welcome back, {{ user.details.name }}</h2>
  <p>
    <button ion-button color="secondary" block>Something</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button ion-button color="secondary" block (click)="chat()">Chat</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button ion-button color="secondary" block (click)="about()">About</button>
  </p>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thank you! It helps
How to do comeback click to homepage??  from about and chat

Comment: @KarolinaBagrowska Please don't expand your question after it has been posted. If your question has been answered mark it as such and if you need further help that cannot be found in search, then open a new question. Thank you.

Comment: to comeback to home. there are 2 ways. first instead of setting about page and chat page as root page you can push them to current nav stack. for this in about and chat methods (home.ts) use `this.navCtrl.push(About);` it will push your about page to current nav stack and back button will appear on about page.

Comment: other way in about component/page make a new button and set the reference of home page on its click as you are doing in home page to goto about and chat page. however pushing page on current nav stack is good approach.

Comment: @KarolinaBagrowska if the answer fixes the issue of the original post, please mark it as accepted so it can be closed. You can find more information about how to accept an answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and how to upvote an answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow).